# \n appears in string is not functional

Tags: android, database, string

when getstring of a database:

```
inf = c.getstring(5);
//inf is equals "Hello how are you?\nFine and you\nI am fine, thanks.";
```

When I print it appears in the same way and does not execute the parameters "\ n":

```
tV1.setText(inf);

//the text "is Hello how are you?\nFine and you\nI am fine, thanks."
```

but I want:

```
 "Hello how are you?
    Fine and you
    I am fine, thanks."
```

What is the problem?

---

**The solution for me:**

```
    String finalInf = inf.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
tV1.setText(finalInf);
```

*Thanks: Skaard-Solo and rest.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try

```
String finalInf = inf.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
tV1.setText(finalInf);


System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

is a system replacement for new line

Comment: no work, i tried String finalInf = inf.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); and String finalInf = inf.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); but nothing.. :(

Comment: Did you set a maxLine in android xml layout ? (And use just \\n)

Comment: Finally i use String finalInf = inf.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); and work fine. The problem was in "\\\n" and "\n" was not correct. the correct is "\\n" -> thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inbuilt line separator

```
 String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like that:

```
String inf = c.getstring(5);
String [] inf2 = inf.split("\\").

for (int i = 0; i < inf2.length(); i++){
  if(i < inf2.length() -1){
    inf += inf2[i].substring(1,inf2[2].length()) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
  }
}
```

Can't be more complicated, I challenge you :)

Comment: there are a problem with this code. give me a error in String [] inf2 = inf.split("\");

Comment: Edited it. Please try now.